# How to design SQL Server table for a relation between same column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database there is a table with my customers. Customers can be producers or traders of products to whom I deliver raw material.

Many producers have trading companies with different names which could be in my database listed as independently customers, further many of them have online-shops again with different names. So who belongs to whom is very difficult to find out and if  I do, I have to "link" them together in my db.

My idea is to add a table with only 2 columns: CuID (customer ID from maintainable) and linked CuID (let's say I call this column ReID=relation ID also holding the CuID of a partner company.).

Whenever I detect one relation between them I add CuID in column CuID and the other companies CuID in column "ReID".

On an Access-form, I have a subform presenting all names of related customers (CuID:ReID  =1:n).

But how can I present it vice versa, when I am on the record of a customer which is stored as ReID and present the CuID in column "CuID"?

Example: 
Company A CuID=1 has ties to Company B CuID=3. In my table, I add 1 / 3
Company X CuID=7 has ties to Company B CuID=3. In my table, I add 7 /3

On form presenting Company A I find related Company B in a subform.
On form presenting Company X I find related Company B in a subform.

How can I present A and B as a relation to Company X on a form when X is presented??

I have not been able to find a proper solution for this requirement.
Any idea appreciated.
Thx Michael

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, you should have two tables:

- `Companies`
- `Shops`

`Customers` should have a primary key, like:

```
create table Companies (
    CompanyId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    Name varchar(255),
    . . .
);
```

Then `Shops`, should refer back to it:

```
create table Shops (
    ShopId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    CompanyId int references Companies(CompanyId),
    . . .
);
```

Presumably, a shop is only related to one company, so you just fill in `Shops.CompanyId` when you spot the relationship.  Only if there is a many-to-many relationship would you need a junction/association table.

Comment: It's a good habit to explicitly assign names to constraints like `CONSTRAINT FK_Shops_Companies FOREIGN KEY (CompanyId) REFERENCES Companies (CompanyId)`.

Comment: I found a really simple solution now, still with my idea of only one table with two columns: SELECT   a.ID, a.KdID , a.RelID
FROM            dbo.tblRelations
UNION ALL
SELECT   a.ID, a.RelID , a.KdID 
FROM            dbo.tblRelations 

Works the way I need it!